# MySQL - How to remove duplicate data entry?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have below kind of data

```
id product_id url
10 300        /300/abc
 9 300        /300/abc/def
 8 200        /200/bcd
 7 200        /200/bcd/efg
 6 100        /100/cde
 5 100        /100/cde/hif
```

Each rows product_id second value is correct means, id 9,7,5 are correct.

```
SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) count FROM demo_table GROUP BY product_id HAVING count > 1;
```

Above query will give me the result which have duplicate values.

How can I delete rest of the records via MySQL query?

Comment: Are there only 2 duplicates for each id or more?

Comment: Hi @forpas 2 duplicates for each id. Yes only

Comment: Is there any logic involved? If not, why not simply run a `DELETE` query with the IDs which are not 5,7,9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a self `join` in the `DELETE` statement:

```
DELETE d1
FROM demo_table d1 INNER JOIN demo_table d2
ON d2.product_id = d1.product_id AND d2.id < d1.id;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2toyAVMacPkdwSFaDJHeCS/0).
Results:

```
| id  | product_id | url          |
| --- | ---------- | ------------ |
| 9   | 300        | /300/abc/def |
| 7   | 200        | /200/bcd/efg |
| 5   | 100        | /100/cde/hif |
```

Comment: Just a question if `product_id` column is like string `/product_id/300' then also works or we need to take different approach for that?

Comment: A condition like `d2.product_id = d1.product_id` can be applied to numbers and strings.

Comment: I mean change `AND d2.id < d1.id` to `AND d2.url > d1.url` better for delete records with short url

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2toyAVMacPkdwSFaDJHeCS/1

Comment: @forpas, yes. it is better solution, based on url lenght